# How to create table with multiple multirows and multi columns

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I try to create a table like to one here:

[image]

I tried many options with `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`, however, after few hours I'm not even close to the final result.

Any ideas how could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code you treid up to now? Did you use the package `multirow` and the command `\multicolumn`?

Comment: I tried different solutions and the current code is not event close to the result I need to achieve.
Yes, I do ude multirow package and multicolumn command.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any information regarding important parameters such as the width of the text block and the intended font size for the words in the table. The following example should only be considered to be a starting-off point for further work by you.

Note the use of the `tabularx` package, the `\arraystretch` command, the `multirow` package and three `\multirow` instructions, several `\cline` instructions, one `\multicolumn` instruction, and the `\small` instruction to enable the table to fit in what some (many?) might consider to be a standard-width text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\caption{A table with multiple multirows}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|*{8}{Y|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & no & more & less & part of & reverse & other than & early & late\\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Create} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{Internal data} & Simple Item &&&&&&&&\\
\cline{3-11}
& & Compound Item &&&&&&&& \\
\cline{3-11}
& & Set &&&&&&&& \\
\cline{2-11}
& \multirow{3}{*}{External data} & Simple Item &&&&&&&&\\
\cline{3-11}
& & Compound Item &&&&&&&& \\
\cline{3-11}
& & Set &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks much better than my approaches :) I need to put text into the cells of the table (the text might be pretty long on some cases, like 100 characters). Now it looks that the cells cannot handle long strings.

Comment: @Jakub - The material in columns 4 thru 11 will be wrapped automatically because of the use of the `Y` column type. However, if what you need to enter long, unbroken strings, then the use of this column type isn't going to help you appreciably. You will probably need to set the table in landscape mode to gain some more space and/or switch to a smaller font size (say, `\footnotesize`). You could also try reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` a bit more, say to `3pt`. Not knowing more details about your table's contents, I'm afraid I can't provide more-specific advice.

Comment: I tried the landscape mode and tabcolsep but it did not help. I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3iy1h0wtynhq74y/table.jpg

Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Jakub - Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "... did not help." Are the cells still not large enough for your purpose, or is there a different issue? Incidentally, I can't help but remark that the table design you're looking to implement is rather oppressive. Do you aspire to have your readers remember three (and maybe more) concrete pieces of information from reading the table? If so, please try hard to simplify the design. As it stands, your table is most likely to be remembered merely as "Oh yeah, a really confusing and mindboggling table - can't remember its contents".